# Plot Variable Frequency using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot a bar graph showing frequency of a string in ggplot. The input file (t1. txt) looks like:

```
do  4
re  2
mi  5
```

and my current r script is:

```
library("ggplot2")
t1<-read.table("t1.txt",header=FALSE,sep='\t')
ggplot(t1,aes(V1))+geom_bar()
```

However this isn't what I'd like - it has a correct x axis, but the y axis should show the variable from the second column (V2). Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is put the actual V2 in the command then.  The default first two items to aes are x and y.  You've only given x.

```
ggplot(t1,aes(V1,V2))+geom_bar()
```